# Manually move to year/month/day in date input with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, dom

Is there a way to manually move to a different "column" (not sure what the terminology is) in the date input field using Javascript / jQuery?

Here is an example of my code and what I'm trying to achieve:

```
//date value is pre populated
$( document ).on( 'keydown change', ':input[type="date"]', function(e) {
    var date = new Date(jQuery(this).val());
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    if(year.toString().length <= 3){
        return true;
    } else {
        //move input to month column
    }
});
```

**Edit:** I should mention that I'm specifically trying to achieve this without using the date min/max attributes. I know I can set those.

**Edit 2:** I'm trying to go from **yyyy**/mm/dd to yyyy/**mm**/dd **inside the html date input** with javascript/jquery. Currently the date field allows the date to be: *yyyyyy*/mm/yy (6 digits). I only want to allow 4 digits and then it should move over to mm.

Comment: Move what to a different column? What column?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm trying to go from **yyyy**/mm/dd to yyyy/**mm**/dd with javascript on user input when condition is met. I've updated my question.

Comment: The date input interaction is handled by the browser. If you want to customise it, you'll need to make your own.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Make my own what? Script? Browser? I'm sure I can write a script for it if I know what DOM element I should target.

Comment: Make your own browser . Sorry I meant make your own "date" input with custom interactions. There's little to no custom interactions you can make for the date input, likely because each browsers implementation is unique. The best you might hope for is manipulating the input value.

Comment: @evolutionxbox lol  ;-) . Ok, think I'll just set them up as three seperate select fields or something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's exactly how [the UK's GDS recommends to do it](https://design-system.service.gov.uk/components/date-input/)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Good to know. Thanks for the reference. :)